# Can't create module dependence in Android Studio 1.5.1

Tags: android, android-studio, module

i got a problem when creating module on android studio. I recently downloaded and updated it.

> The problem is when I create a new module for my project, it won't
>   compile as a module.

Trying to add it manually in the `settings.gradle` and still not working and I can't figure out.

[image]

*This image represent the module I created normally going to `File > New > New Module`*

The Module gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
   }

   dependencies {
      compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
      testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
      compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
      compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
      compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
  }
```

and the `settings.gradle`

`include ':app', ':rest'`

> The question is, this is a bug? How can I figure out this problem?

Note: Before version 1.5 of Android Studio it was working.

EDIT

`./gradle projects` results

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

Root project 'ProjectMaster-NoDatabase'
+--- Project ':app'
\--- Project ':rest'

To see a list of the tasks of a project, run gradlew <project-path>:tasks
For example, try running gradlew :app:tasks

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 55.561 secs
```

Comment: Please post  `./gradlew projects` result

Comment: @MenTaka I added the logs

Comment: do you have a `build.gradle` file in rest?

Comment: @nexus5x Yes, is the gradle code I posted above

Comment: Thanks! And please post `./gradlew androidDependencies`

Comment: @MenTaka i solve. I just deleted the folder .idea and opened the project again.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem i did this:

1 - Delete the `.idea` folder from the project structure.

2 - Then reopen the project.

The project will open the folders as modules.