# Android Studio ignores module

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have application module, 4 android lib modules, and 2 java modules. I'm trying to add one more android lib module, but AS ignores it.

New module is created and added to settings.gradle. AS does not add *.iml file to module folder, and .idea/gradle.xml and ./idea/modules.xml files don't contain records about new module. I tried to generate *.iml file by myself, and added records to .idea/ files. It starts working, but then i got message

> The modules below are not backed by Gradle anymore. Check those to be
>   removed from the ide project too

, and *.iml file was removed.

AS 2.2.3, gradle 2.14.1

UPD 1.

The problem was in unexpected place. I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34615435/cant-create-module-dependence-in-android-studio-1-5-1), because it was very similiar to my problem, tried to delete module and add it again (with new name). But nothing helped. After opening Gradle tab (right top corner), I found that new module was highlighted with dark grey color, right-clicked on it, and saw that "Ignore Gradle project" was checked by default.

[image: Dropdown menu]

I unchecked this item, but after next gradle sync I got above message, and this item was checked again automatically. Also in event log

> Unsupported Modules Detected: Compilation is not supported for following modules: modulename. Unfortunately you can't have non-Gradle Java modules and Android-Gradle modules in one project.

UPD 2.
Seems like https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77983 and https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230550

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution that helped me:

1. Close AS
2. Remove all *.iml files
3. Remove .idea dir
4. Remove .gradle dir
5. Rename project
6. Open project with AS

Comment: just removing .idea and .gradle folders worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
android {

   ...

    buildTypes {

        ...

        dexOptions {
            preDexLibraries true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I met the same trouble. It is my solution, add the gradle code into your failed modules gradle file.